# How can I create inhomogen background with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create some kind of texture for the background of my HTML text. Can I do something like that in css?

Comment: Wait, I'll be right back after a quick look at my dictionary...

Comment: Something like this, with `mask-image`? http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/

Comment: I don't want to use images for that purpose that's supposed to be inefficient. Although I don't really know if there's a real difference in efficiency between mask-image or css magic.

Comment: @Mr.Alien if you know the words better then feel free to correct them.

Comment: @qben I went to take my dictionary that shows am not aware of the meaning so can't provide a better word,also am equally noob ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

With CSS 3 you can do something like this.

http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#

Example usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <style>
        body {
            background:
            radial-gradient(hsl(0, 100%, 27%) 4%, hsl(0, 100%, 18%) 9%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 9%) 0 0,
            radial-gradient(hsl(0, 100%, 27%) 4%, hsl(0, 100%, 18%) 8%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 10%) 50px 50px,
            radial-gradient(hsla(0, 100%, 30%, 0.8) 20%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0)) 50px 0,
            radial-gradient(hsla(0, 100%, 30%, 0.8) 20%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0)) 0 50px,
            radial-gradient(hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 1) 35%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 60%) 50px 0,
            radial-gradient(hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 1) 35%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 60%) 100px 50px,
            radial-gradient(hsla(0, 100%, 15%, 0.7), hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0)) 0 0,
            radial-gradient(hsla(0, 100%, 15%, 0.7), hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0)) 50px 50px,
            linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 49%, hsla(0, 100%, 0%, 1) 50%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 70%) 0 0,
            linear-gradient(-45deg, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 49%, hsla(0, 100%, 0%, 1) 50%, hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0) 70%) 0 0;
            background-color: #300; 
            background-size: 100px 100px;       
        }

    </style>
</head> 
<body> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no easy css solution, if this hard ;)   Use images instead.